# JavaScript append two files first line with first line

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running a local server with NodeJs. I want to append two text files with JavaScript by taking the first line of the first one and the first line of the second text file and so on.

```
text1.txt:                        text2.txt

First                              Fourth
Second                             Fifth
Third                              Sixth
```

Expected output:

```
First Fourth
Second Fifth
Third Sixth
```

JavaScript:

```
var text1 = fs.readFile('data1.txt','utf8');
var text1Split = text1.split(\n);

var text2 = fs.readFile('data2.txt','utf8');
var text2Split = text2.split(\n);

concat([
  'text2',
  'text1.txt',
], 'file.txt', function(err) {
   if (err) throw err
});
```

Obviously the concatenation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating two arrays using 'concat'

```
array1.concat(array2, array3, ..., arrayX)
```

So concatenate arrays to single array and overwrite that array to the file whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text1 = fs.readFile('data1.txt','utf8');
var text1Split = text1.split(\n);

var text2 = fs.readFile('data2.txt','utf8');
var text2Split = text2.split(\n);

var both = text2Split.concat(text1Split)
```